# DBT incremental materialization on huge BigQuery use a full scan

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have a massive table on BigQuery that I want to load incrementally to save BigQuery processing.

This is the pseudo code/configuration:

```
config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite',
    partition_by = {'field': 'load_date', 'data_type': 'date'}
)
}}


select * from {{ source('huge_table') }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
    where load_date >= (select max(load_date) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

The table is partitioned on the `load_date` column, and I would expect to have the `max(load_date)` to optimize the query and use the last partition.

Instead, the query is performing a full scan and consuming many resources.

Does anybody know how to optimize this DBT loading?

Comment: would you be able to add a lookback window of X days to look for new row values (e.g. last 3 days only)?

Answer (score 1):

If that’s your full config, then I think the issue is using the `insert_overwrite` strategy without specifying a `partitions` key.

There is a great write up by Jeremy Cohen [here](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/bigquery-dbt-incremental-changes/982).

But basically, if you’re replacing a fixed set of partitions, just define those in the config, and the optimizer will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While it idiomatic in DBT, I don't think using a Subquery is optimized when combined with pruning BQ partitions

So, the culprit might be: `where load_date >= (select max(load_date) from {{ this }})`

Reading the [BQ Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#better_performance_with_pseudo-columns), using table values created dynamically (i.e. the above subquery from `this`) may not be helpful when optimizing your query. Rather, you might want to use a call statement that pre-fetches the max `load_date` from the existing table, and then uses jinja to resolve it in your query. For example:

```sql
{% if is_incremental() %}
  {%- call statement('state', fetch_result=True) -%}

    select max(load_date) from {{ this }}

  {%- endcall -%}

  {%- set prev_max_date = state['data'][0][0] -%}
{% endif %}

select * from {{ source('huge_table') }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
    where load_date >= DATE prev_max_date
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the partitions to replace, you should try using [**static partitions**](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#static-partitions) method that is [cheapest and almost always fastest](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/benchmarking-incremental-strategies-on-bigquery/981) to avoid the full table scan:

```
{% set partitions_to_replace = [
  'timestamp(current_date)',
  'timestamp(date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day))'
] %}

config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite',
    partition_by = {'field': 'load_date', 'data_type': 'date'},
    partitions = partitions_to_replace
)
}}


select * from {{ source('huge_table') }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
    -- recalculate yesterday + today
    where timestamp_trunc(load_date, day) in ({{ partitions_to_replace | join(',') }})
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise, you can use **[dynamic partitions](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs#dynamic-partitions)** method with the `_dbt_max_partition` variable instead of your `select MAX(...) from` to dynamic prune the partitions.

```
config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite',
    partition_by = {'field': 'load_date', 'data_type': 'date'}
)
}}


select * from {{ source('huge_table') }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
    -- NOTE: The _dbt_max_partition variable is used to introspect the destination table
    where date(load_date) >= date(_dbt_max_partition)
{% endif %}
```